# Is it possible to dynamically define a constant in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to find a way to dynamically define a constant in Typescript but I'am starting to thing it's not possible.

I tried this :

```
  define(name: string, value: any): boolean {
    var undef;
    const name = value;
    return name == undef;
  }
```

I am supposed to call:

```
define ('MY_CONST_NAME', 'foo_value);
```

I get the following error :

```
Duplicate 'name' identifier.
```

I think it's normal but i don't know how to achieve my goal.

Comment: You're getting that error because you have a function parameter and a local variable with the same name. Use different names, or clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: we'd need more context (how you'd call `define` for example). Here the error is normal, you have `name` defined in the function parameters and inside the scope.

Comment: I get it but I just want to create a constant in my function and return a boolean if I succeed or not

Comment: Does this satisfy your requirements? `const somethingElse = value; return somethingElse == undef`. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Nicholas, with your way i cannot define my constant name with my function. I update my question @ValLeNain

Comment: This constant is only going to be visible inside the function anyway. It's a local variable.

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO you've edited in how you want to call the function. But we also need to know what you expect the result to be? What is supposed to be different after it has been called?

Comment: @NicholasTower I wrote it, it's my first line : my function define a constant, so nothing change i just create a new variable but i understand. My code won't work this way

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO if your question has been answered please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question made no sense but there is a workaround to achieve this using types:

```
type Dynamic = Record<string, string>

const myDynamicsVars: Dynamic = {}

myDynamicsVars.name = "toto"

console.log(myDynamicsVars.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

In short... No. Const is block scoped. When declared it becomes available and not until then. If you want to declare something as immutable it's not that hard, but this question shows a lack of knowledge possibly. I think what you may find more useful is how to deep freeze an object so things can't be added to, taken off of, or changed in it. However it is shallow, so deep changes would be an issue unless you want to freeze it recursively(CAREFUL) or on a path

[From the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
var obj = {
  prop: function() {},
  foo: 'bar'
};

// New properties may be added, existing properties may be
// changed or removed
obj.foo = 'baz';
obj.lumpy = 'woof';
delete obj.prop;

// Both the object being passed as well as the returned
// object will be frozen. It is unnecessary to save the
// returned object in order to freeze the original.
var o = Object.freeze(obj);

o === obj; // true
Object.isFrozen(obj); // === true

// Now any changes will fail
obj.foo = 'quux'; // silently does nothing
// silently doesn't add the property
obj.quaxxor = 'the friendly duck';

// In strict mode such attempts will throw TypeErrors
function fail(){
  'use strict';
  obj.foo = 'sparky'; // throws a TypeError
  delete obj.quaxxor; // throws a TypeError
  obj.sparky = 'arf'; // throws a TypeError
}

fail();

// Attempted changes through Object.defineProperty; 
// both statements below throw a TypeError.
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'ohai', { value: 17 });
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', { value: 'eit' });

// It's also impossible to change the prototype
// both statements below will throw a TypeError.
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, { x: 20 })
obj.__proto__ = { x: 20 }
```

Comment: ah ah thank you for: "this question shows a lack of knowledge possibly" by the way, it'as a good answer, I was pretty sure that i was trying ssomething impossible.